# Under what conditions does $(M/A)\oplus (N/C)\cong B\oplus D$ imply $M/A\cong B$ and $N/C\cong D$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

For a commutative ring $R$ with unity and $R$-modules $M$ and $N$, let $A$ and $B$ be submodules of $M$, and  $C$ and $D$ be submodules of $N$ such that $$M/B\cong A~\text{ and}~N/D\cong C.$$   If $(M/A)\oplus (N/C)\cong B\oplus D,$ then  when do we have to conclude that $$M/A\cong B~\text{and}~N/C\cong D~?$$  What conditions allow one to come to that conclusion.

All the attempts I have encountered only provide for counter-examples of the ''$A\oplus B\cong C\oplus D$'' does not necessarily imply $A\cong C$ and $B\cong D$.